# read an integer list and return into a format python

Tags: list, merge, integer

If I open a file with the following in it:
1 2 3 4 \n
5 6 7 \n
8 9 10

so

```
def read(list):
  list = open('list.tet','r')
  nums = list.readlines()
  new_list = []
  for num in nums:
    if num.find('\n'):
      new_list.append(num.strip('\n')
  return new_list
```

I hope to get the output as
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

What should I do?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to read out your integers if you have a fix seperator ( like the space ):

```
new_list = []
with open( "list.tet", "r" ) as myFile:
    for myLine in myFile:
        for myInt in myLine.strip().split( " " ):
            new_list.append( myInt )

print( "Integers:", new_list )
```

It is not the perfect python way as you can compress those lines even more but I thought that it is a bit easier to understand. The good thing is that you have built in failure handling if the file 'list.tet' is missing.

The example will open your file and read one line after another as 'myLine'. Than it will strip any leading/trailing spaces/tabs/newline characters from this line leaving you with "1 2 3" for the first line. The split than separate those into [1, 2, 3] we use in the for loop to put each value into myInt that than got appended to your new_list.

Comment: You don't need the readlines function as the for loop iterates over all the lines for you.